# Game engine that allows for objects being placed in-game

Tags: networking, multiplayer, terrain, udp

I am looking for a game engine with multiplayer support that allows for players to place objects in the terrain. (eg. in TF2 one can place teleporters, etc... or in minecraft one can place blocks). I don't need the placeable objects to be interactive like in TF2, but I just need an engine that won't make me code this from scratch. I have decent knowledge of Python, PHP, HTML, C++ and C# (and a small knowledge of Lua scripting, although I have only been at it for a few months) so I should be able to handle most engines. So far I have looked at UDK and Cryengine, and wasn't thrilled with either.

Comment: Pretty much any engine will allow you to do this. Just think of spawning enemies, A.K.A. adding new objects. So are you mainly looking for the multi-player part?

Comment: Yes, im looking for an engine that allows this, but in a way that allows a multiplayer system. This would mean that most of what happens would happen on the server side, not the client side, in order to make it harder to cheat.

Comment: Can you elaborate on what features you're looking to add and how it "didn't run well"?

Comment: @Byte56 thank you for your guidance, I'm new here. I just typed something up above, as I think its a bit long for a comment.

Comment: No problem, I modified it a bit, since it shouldn't be for me. I'm sorry I don't have a recommendation for you, I'm just trying to get enough information so that someone else might be able to answer it.

Comment: Not to be nitpicky but doesn't this fall under ["what technology should I use?"](http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/faq) I'm having trouble figuring out how this question can have a definitive "right" answer since any engine (at it's core) is capable of this but it might take some work on the programmers side to do it.

Comment: You may have to roll up your sleeves and implement some of these features yourself.  Cube may be a good starting point.  I also head UDK 4 may have some of these features.  Otherwise, adding basic "create new object" features to any multiplayer game should be straight forward.

Comment: @Mike C, Thank you for your feedback, but I disagree, as I'm asking for any engine that supports this, not for the "best" game engine or the "most suggested" game engine or anything like that. After some research, I have found that it doesn't seem very easy to find an engine that has documentation for this in a networked environment. This led me to believe that it may be an engine-specific feature, but after reading your reply along with others, I have become educated on the matter, and now understand that it is not.

Comment: @seanmiddleditch Thanks for the suggestion along with the Cube 2 answer. It is greatly appreciated. I have experimented with UDK, but am not a big fan of its networking system, and since it doesn't come with a source licence, i don't believe I can implement other libraries to do it differently.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I would like to thank everyone for their feedback, but ultimately I have settled on the Torque engine due to the good networking capabilities which I hope will make accomplishing my goals easier. It also offers scripting in "TorqueScript" which seems very easy to learn and it seems to be capable of accomplishing what I desire to make with the engine.

Answer (score 0):

http://cubeengine.com/

Cube is one of the first engines I recall seeing that had great multi-user editing capabilities.

Answer (score 0):

This question probably needs to be [closed for being "inappropriate"](https://gamedev.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/695/are-what-should-i-use-to-do-x-questions-really-on-topic-and-good) or, at least, needs to be converted to CW since there is no right answer.

In the spirit of sharing relevant information:  [Unity](http://www.unity3d.com/) is one of *many* engines that can support client-side creation of objects.  Networking is fairly straight forward for setting up a P2P connection and the [`Network.Instantiate()` function](http://unity3d.com/support/documentation/Components/net-NetworkInstantiate.html) makes it pretty simple to make objects that all connected players can see.

Comment: Thank you for the help. Sorry, but I was having issues finding documentation supporting this in any engine, so (comming from developing security software and being new to game development) I wasn't sure if this was a feature that only specific engines supported over a network environment (like deformable terrain)

Comment: In regards to your suggest for closing the topic, I believe my question shouldn't be closed as I have a specific question with specific requirements, and for newcomers to the game development world, considering that there isn't too much documentation regarding this from a simple google search, this topic is a good research point for developers who wish to implement similar features.